# Two legend items for one series

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have a chart on which I'm using two colours for one series: red for values below a certain value and green for above.

Is there a way I could display two items in the legend for this series? So far I've tried using `Iif` in the legend's expression, but it returns only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add 2 calculated fields in your dataset one for below and one above. Here you can use 2 `IIf`statements to separate the values in your chart.

Alternatively you should be able to add the field in question to the chart twice and add an expression as above to each one for above and below.

In either of these cases there will be 2 entries in the legend.

I hope I'm on the right track for you however I can't test this at the moment.

Comment: I solved the problem by hiding original series legend and creating two "dummy" series with value expression of "=0", just to add the legend items.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this a little bit ago for a pie chart but not with colors.  Do you have to have the colors be shown or could you set a custom array of colors up and reference that instead?

In my problem I had to list 'ranges' of percentages occurring. (Someone wanted things in a range to be counted instead of individual counts).

I created a dataset 'DataforPie':

```
Declare @temp table ( id int identity, name varchar(8), perc decimal(2,1)) 

insert into @temp values ( 'Brett', .9),( 'Brett', .5),( 'Brett', .4),( 'Brett', .3)
                        ,( 'John', .1), ( 'John', .3),( 'John', .4),( 'John', .2)
                        ,( 'Brian', .5), ( 'Brian', .6),( 'Brian', .5),( 'Brian', .3)

select *
from @temp
```

I then set up a pie chart with the 'values' being [count(perc)] and an expression for the 'grouping' and 'labeling' of a 'Category Group' defined as:

```
=Switch(

Fields!perc.Value >= 0.6, "Greater than 6",
Fields!perc.Value >= 0.3, "Greater than 3",
Fields!perc.Value >= 0, "Greater than 0"
)
```

Now with your issue since you want custom colors I think you may wish to define a palette expression to determine colors.  There is a good example of this here, even if it is a previous version it should still be similar: http://www.cubido.at/blogs/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1256

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar problem and I solved it using the following steps:

1. Add the mentioned value field in the series group section
2. Right click the added series group and select series group properties
3. Add an expression in the Label Field e.g `=IIF(Fields!abc.Value<=10,"TenOrLess",...)`
4. In the fill section select gradient and select "No Color" in Color and set an expression in the Secondary Color e.g. `=IIF(Fields!abc.Value<=10,"Red",...)`
5. Click on series and in its properties window under the CustomAttributes section set DrawSideBySide to False